# Como dividir igualmente o espaço do StackPanel entre os filhos

Tags: wpf, grid, inline

Tenho um Stack Panel com alguns botões dentro, quero que o espaço disponível do Stack seja dividido igualmente entre os botões.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Content="USUÁRIOS" Height="auto"/>
            <Button Content="IM" Height="auto" />
            <Button Content="COMPOSIÇÃO" Height="auto" />
            <Button Content="DEFEITOS" Height="auto" />
            <Button Content="PERDAS" Height="auto" />
            <Button Content="DIÁRIO" Height="auto" />
            <Button Content="GERENCIAR" Height="auto" />
            <Button Content="GED" Height="auto"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

A saída é a seguinte: [image: Captura]

Quero que os botões preencham todo esse espaço em branco com tamanhos iguais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O stackpanel não seria muito usual nesse caso, eu recomendo você usar um grid e definir as colunas dele distribuindo os botões em cada uma das colunas.

```
<Grid Height="35">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Content="USUÁRIOS" Height="auto" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Button Content="IM" Height="auto"  Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Button Content="COMPOSIÇÃO" Height="auto" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Button Content="DEFEITOS" Height="auto" Grid.Column="3"/>
    <Button Content="PERDAS" Height="auto" Grid.Column="4"/>
    <Button Content="DIÁRIO" Height="auto" Grid.Column="5"/>
    <Button Content="GERENCIAR" Height="auto" Grid.Column="6"/>
    <Button Content="GED" Height="auto" Grid.Column="7"/>
</Grid>
```

Onde o "Grid.ColumnsDefinition" divide a grid na quantidade de "ColumnDefinition" que você inserir. Nos botões você somente define cada um em sua respectiva coluna. Ao aumentar ou diminuir a tela em tempo de execução, seus botões continuarão ajustados uniformemente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]